# Incorrect logical indexing?

Tags: python-3.x

For the code:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("/Users/Akshita/Desktop/EE660/donor_raw_data_medmean.csv", header=None, names=None)
# Separate data and label
X_label = dataset[1:19373][0]
X_data = dataset[1:19373]

print(X_data[X_label==1])
```

I get the output:(There are actually 4000~ samples with label=1)

```
0    1   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  ...   51  52   53  54  55  56  57     58  \
16386  1   17  60  0  1  0  0  0  0  1 ...    0  20   20  20   5  10  15   15   
16396  1  137  60  0  1  0  0  0  0  1 ...   15  25   10  15   6  14  16  120   
16399  1   89  54  0  1  0  0  0  0  1 ...   10  15    5  15   6  14  16   79   
16402  1   89  75  0  1  0  0  0  0  1 ...   25  35   10  35   6  13  15   79   
..
.. 
19356  1  101  80  1  0  0  1  0  0  2 ...   25  30    5  28   7  16  18  101   
19363  1   65  70  1  0  0  1  0  0  1 ...    7  12    5  10   4   8  20   63   
19372  1   29  70  0  0  0  1  0  0  2 ...    0  25   25  25   4   9  24   24   
..
[859 rows x 61 columns]
```

and for

```
print(X_data[X_label==0])
```

I get the output:(There  are about 15000~ samples with label=0)

```
   0    1   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  ...  51  52  53  54  55  56  57   58  \
16384  0   17  74  0  1  0  0  0  0  1 ...   0  15  15  15   4  10  17   17   
16385  0   17  60  0  1  0  0  0  0  2 ...   0  15  15  15   4  11  17   17   
16387  0   29  67  0  1  0  0  0  0  1 ...   0  20  20  20   5  11  23   28   
16388  0   53  60  0  1  0  0  0  0  1 ...   5  30  25  30   5  11  26   52   
16389  0   65  49  0  1  0  0  0  0  1 ...  30  35   5  27   6  13  16   56   
..
..  
19369  0  137  77  1  0  1  0  0  0  1 ...   9  10   1  10   6  13  21  130   
19370  0   29  60  1  0  0  1  0  0  1 ...   0  15  15  15   3   9  23   23   
19371  0  129  78  1  0  0  1  0  0  2 ...  20  25   5  25   7  24   8  129
```

What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: Your code in incomplete (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  What is `pd`?  What module does it come from.  Numpy? Pandas?   Whatever it is, you need an additional tag, because it not an stdlib object.

Comment: Your code seems inefficiently backwards.  If `X_data` is defined first, then I presume `X_label = X_data[0]` should work.  What seems odd is that the sequence numbers (which I presume are not in the file) start with `16384` instead of `1` or `00001`.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Thanks for your comments. pd is pandas(was just trying to cut down on some lines when posting this question). I am very new to Python so I apologize for the inefficiency. My question is precisely those incorrect outputs. My data starts from 1 to 19373.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to examine `dataset` immediately after the first line.  If `print(len(dataset))` works, what does it print?  How about `print(dataset[:10])`?

Comment: @TerryJanReedy The statement "X_data[X_label==0]" was incorrect. Thanks for helping me!